# Compare a given version number in the form major.minor.build.patch and see if one is less than the other

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef int STATUS;
#define ERROR -1
#define OKAY 0

struct version
{
    unsigned char major;
    unsigned char minor;
    unsigned char build;
    unsigned char patch;
};
STATUS is_less_than(struct version * original, struct version *compared, bool *result)
{
    if(original == NULL || compared == NULL || result == NULL)
    {
        result = NULL;
        return ERROR;
    }
    *result = false;

    if(original->major < compared->major)
    {
        *result = true;
    }
    else if(original->major == compared->major) // else if the major >= major
        {

            if(original->minor < compared->minor)
            {
                *result = true;
            }
            else if(original->minor == compared->minor)
            {
                if(original->build < compared->build)
                {
                    *result = true;
                }
                else if(original->build == compared->build)
                {
                    if(original->patch < compared->patch)
                    {
                        *result = true;
                    }
                    else if(original->patch == compared->patch)
                    {
                        *result = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    return OKAY;

}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: [Code golf version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171050/58251), just for fun

Comment: If the build number is monotonically increasing, you could just compare the build number

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there is a cleaner way:

```
if (a.major != b.major) {
    *result = a.major < b.major;
} else if (a.minor != b.minor) {
    *result = a.minor < b.minor;
} else if (a.patch != b.patch) {
    *result = a.patch < b.patch;
} else {
    *result = a.build < b.build;
}
return OKAY;
```

I reordered patch to come before build since that's [how it is usually done](https://semver.org/). If your version scheme is different from this, good luck.

Instead of `unsigned char` I would choose `uint32_t` so that your code can handle versions like `1.0.20190415`. If you need to handle version numbers with millisecond timestamps, each version component would need to be `uint64_t`.

Comment: Nice catch on the patch, build ordering.

Comment: If you really want to handle versions like `1.0.20190415`, `unsigned int` is not portable enough; `unsigned long` is.

Comment: Since when is 1.0.20190415 valid? Version resources can't handle > 65535 in any component.

Comment: @Joshua what is "version resources"? Maven can, and pkgsrc also. I guess pkg-config can handle the same, and so on.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Win32 and .NET file versions are built into the binaries using a structure known as a version resource.

Comment: @Joshua I don't see anything in the question about Win32 or .Net.

Comment: @L.F. Thanks for the suggestion, I've chosen `uint32_t` now, at least.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any advantage to having the function take three pointers (two for input and one for output) and return a status code.  As a result of that **unnecessarily error-prone design**, the function has to handle the possibility of null pointers, and the caller is expected to handle a status code.  But why should such a simple comparison have these failure modes at all?

The danger is further complicated by the fact that neither of the in-parameters is declared `const`.

**Just pass the two versions by value**, and you would eliminate all of that complication!  On any modern 32-bit or 64-bit processor, passing a four-byte struct by value should actually be more efficient than passing it by reference — especially since you don't have to dereference the pointers to access each field.

With all of the potential errors out of the way, taking @RolandIllig's suggestion, you could then reduce it down to one chained conditional expression:

```
bool is_less_than(struct version a, struct version b) {
    return a.major != b.major ? a.major < b.major :
           a.minor != b.minor ? a.minor < b.minor :
           a.patch != b.patch ? a.patch < b.patch :
                                a.build < b.build;
}
```

I'd go further and recommend **using `unsigned short` instead of `unsigned char` for the fields**.  Using `unsigned char` for numeric values is awkward, since you would have to cast them when using `printf()`.  On a 64-bit architecture, a struct with four 2-byte fields would occupy 64 bits, so you wouldn't be saving anything by using `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned short`. It's also entirely conceivable that you might need mire than 256 builds within a patch level.

Comment: That code really looks beautiful. There's one thing I don't get though. Can you elaborate on the "you would have to cast them" part? To my knowledge, when used in `printf("%u", a.major)`, both `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` behave the same. The different behavior would only occur in C++, when doing `std::cout << a.major`. This is a C question though.

Comment: @RolandIllig You're right: type promotion would happen implicitly with `printf("%d", a.major)`, so it wouldn't be a significant concern.

Answer (score 4):

## Return status

You create this:

```
typedef int STATUS;
#define ERROR -1
#define OKAY 0
```

which is basically a boolean status. Personally, I'd return a straight `bool`.

## Bug/Not what you mean

Doing a

```
result = NULL;
```

is changing the local variable (parameter) `result`. It's not setting the result to NULL. In fact the caller won't probably have a pointer at all, but just a `bool`, which cannot properly be NULL.

## Shorter version

I'm not sure this is cleaner, but here I go:

```
bool is_less_than(struct version * original, struct version *compared, bool *result)
{
    if(original == NULL || compared == NULL || result == NULL)
        return false;
    
    *result = original->major < compared->major || original->major == compared->major && (
              original->minor < compared->minor || original->minor == compared->minor && (
              original->build < compared->build || original->build == compared->build && (
              original->patch < compared->patch)));

    return true;
}
```

Next time, add a driver/test suite to your question, to ease the life of people answering. This can be one:

```
int main(void) 
{
    struct version ref      = { 1, 2, 21, 8 };
    struct version lower1   = { 0, 2, 21, 8 };
    struct version lower2   = { 1, 1, 21, 8 };
    struct version lower3   = { 1, 2, 20, 8 };
    struct version lower4   = { 1, 2, 21, 7 };
    struct version equal    = { 1, 2, 21, 8 };
    struct version higher1  = { 2, 2, 21, 8 };
    struct version higher2  = { 1, 3, 21, 8 };
    struct version higher3  = { 1, 2, 22, 8 };
    struct version higher4  = { 1, 2, 21, 9 };

#define TEST(a,b,expect1,expect2)\
    do {\
        bool result1, result2;\
        is_less_than((a), (b), &result1);\
        is_less_than((b), (a), &result2);\
        puts(result1==(expect1) && result2==(expect2)?"ok":"failed");\
    } while(0)
#define TESTL(a,b) TEST(a,b,true,false)
#define TESTE(a,b) TEST(a,b,false,false)
#define TESTH(a,b) TEST(a,b,false,true)

    TESTL(&lower1, &ref);
    TESTL(&lower2, &ref);
    TESTL(&lower3, &ref);
    TESTL(&lower4, &ref);
    TESTE(&equal, &ref);
    TESTH(&higher1, &ref);
    TESTH(&higher2, &ref);
    TESTH(&higher3, &ref);
    TESTH(&higher4, &ref);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As for every comparator function, the driver/test should compare each pair of example data to at least ensure that the ordering is transitive and that `less(x, x)` is never true.

Comment: @RolandIllig Updated. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What is a "driver" in this context?

Comment: @the_endian it's the program that runs the tests. Probably a really bad word play based on the "test driver" for cars. There's also the related term "compiler driver" for the main program of GCC or Clang that calls the internal subprograms like the preprocessor, the actual compiler, the assembler and the linker.

Comment: @the_endian Testing software requires "stubs" and "drivers", which are substituted for modules or functions that call or are called by the one being tested. Stubs are functions called by the function being tested, and return constant or determined values so that the testing is predictable. Drivers are functions that call the function being tested with constant values. My interpretation of the names has always been that "stubs" are shorter (stubbier) than the real functions as they don't do anything, and "drivers" provide impetus to the functions being tested like a screw driver, etc.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stub. This terminology comes from before unit testing frameworks were common, and now I feel old.